# How to resolve the "A different origin subframe tried to create a JavaScript dialog" warning in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain, xss

I'm getting this warning in Chrome when I try to show a dialog (`alert()`/`confirm()`/`prompt()`) from an iframe. Both domains belong to me.

> A different origin subframe tried to create a JavaScript dialog. This is no longer allowed and was blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576 for more details.

Could I resolve this via `.htaccess` or with an HTTP header or anything like that?

Comment: _“Could I prevent it with .htaccess or http header etc?”_ - don’t see how, other than proxying all requests to the second origin, so that they appear as coming from the first one to the client. But in that case, it’d probably make more sense, to serve all content from the same origin to begin with.

Comment: _“both domains belong to me”_ - then you could perhaps use `postMessage` to send a message to the parent page, trigger the alert/confirm/prompt _from_ there, and then send the result back into the frame using the same method … Not sure if that is feasible or worth the effort (but we don’t know what exactly the purpose is yet either.)

Comment: A solution would be very helpful here.  This has broken our corporate app quite badly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top.alert()`, `top.confirm()`, & `top.prompt()` instead, which, if you have your CORS set up, will use the parent window's (if there is one) dialogs which are not blocked by this Chrome update.

Comment: This has little to do with CORS.

Comment: You can't use CORS to communicate between frames, you need postMessage for that

Comment: I literally just did this on my sites, so.. it's the reason I came across this question; my departments users came across this problem.